# Scilab fsolve returning incorrect argument (error 98)

Tags: function, equation, solver, scilab, nonlinear-functions

I am trying to run `fsolve` to resolve a dissociation equation but I keep getting this error. I tracked it down to the `x(1)^(1/2)` term (removing the square root yields no error) but I can't find a way to solve the proper equation I need. The code is below.

```
T = 2000
Kp = exp(-deltaG/(Ru*T))

function [f]=func(x)
    f(1) = 2-x(1)*4 / (3*x(1) - 1)*(x(1))^(1/2) - Kp
endfunction

x0 = [1]
[x,f_x] = fsolve(x0,func)
```

**EDIT: More requested info**

The error is

> !--error 98  variable returned by scilab argument function is
>   incorrect

`Ru` is the gas constant, `8.315`.

`DeltaG` is `-135643`.

`Kp` is `3.489e-3`.

This is a book example, `x` should yield `0.3334`.

What kind of solved this problem was that I updated scilab to version 6.0.1 from 5.5. The problem is that depending on the initial guess `x0` the values of `x` get really absurd and `x0` has to be so close to the real answer that it defeats the purpose of the calculation.

Also I don't have access to Maple, my other alternative would be MATLAB

Comment: Can you tell us what the expected result shouldo be? And what values did you use for ``detalG`` and ``Ru``? You need to add this information to your question.

Comment: Also, you should paste the error you got.

Comment: Looking at your code, since you're computing a square root, you may end up with a complex value depending on the value of deltaG and R. `fsolve` only works with reals. So it is mandatory you answer @luispauloml question's.

Comment: You guys are right, sorry. I will edit the question.

Comment: There is one big problem with your function: the derivative of ``func`` is very close to zero for all points, expect near the discontinuity around 0.3333  which is also very close to the solution of ``func``(see https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8AoI.png). Because of that, ``fsolve`` returns terminator indicator no. 4, that means "iteration is not making good progress." You should try other method such as ``optim`` or ``fminsearch`` which allows you to choose and tune different algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Using symbolic calculus software like xcas or Maple one can solve your equation symbolycally 
There are 3 solutions:

```
  s1=((1/4)*t1+(1/4)*(Kp-2)^2/t1-(1/4)*Kp+1/2)^2

  s2=(-(1/8)*t1-(1/8)*(Kp-2)^2/t1-(1/4)*Kp+1/2+(1/2*%i)*sqrt(3)*((1/4)*t1-(1/4)*(Kp-2)^2/t1))^2

  s3=(-(1/8)*t1-(1/8)*(Kp-2)^2/t1-(1/4)*Kp+1/2-(1/2*%i)*sqrt(3)*((1/4)*t1-(1/4)*(Kp-2)^2/t1))^2
```

where

```
  t=sqrt(-Kp*(Kp-4)*(Kp-2)^2)
  t1=(-(Kp-2)*(Kp-2*sqrt(2))*(Kp+2*sqrt(2))+4*t)^(1/3);
```

depending on Kp values some solutions can be complex.